# Two way sync adapter in Android

Tags: android

I have gone through a number of links and have spend a huge amount of time over this. Can someone please let me know the simplest approach to implement the Sync Adapter in Android which is 2 way. I mean the changes made on the remote database get reflected on the Android Device and the changes from the device should get updated on the server too.

Also, how to edit the contacts from the default contacts app editor??

Comment: i assume you'd have to do some sort of polling or pushing of data to each device with your app to reflect changes made on the remote server

Comment: in this case, can we use the default contact app to insert new contact or edit the existing contact?

Comment: Try this library: https://github.com/sschendel/SyncManagerAndroid